# Resizing a table column in Microsoft Word and Outlook without affecting adjacent columns

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, text-formatting, layout

When changing the width of a column of a table in Outlook, rather than change the size of the whole table, it "takes" or "gives" width to/from the column to the right of it (so that the width of the whole table remains constant).

Is there a way to resize so that only the width of one column is affected, and the adjacent columns simply shift position accordingly (as if changing column width in a spreadsheet)?

I'm using outlook 2010, but I tried pasting to Word, and found the same behavior.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold down the `SHIFT` key while resizing the column border with the mouse. This will keep the other columns width as is.

Note that by default Outlook uses Word as its message editor. That's why you saw the same behavior in both products.

Comment: What about outlook live online? Table wants to grow uncontrollably. I cant resize it down.