# Cannot resize one column separate from the entire table

Tags: microsoft-word

I would like to resize the last column in my table, without resizing the entire table. However, when I attempt to do this by pulling the border of the final column  out, the entire table resizes. I would like the table to stay put, and to resize this final column by itself.

UPDATE: Thought I found the answer [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1133285/resizing-a-table-column-in-microsoft-word-and-outlook-without-affecting-adjacent) , but it didn't work. Trying to adjust leftmost border of the first column or the rightmost border of the last column resizes the entire table, even when using `SHIFT` + drag.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Bring up Table Properties and select 'Options'.
Uncheck 'Automatically resize to fit contents'.
From there, I was able to edit the column width's manually (as per other answer).

Answer (score 0):

Select the column, right click and change the width to a larger number.

You might need several tries to get it how you want it, but that way, you only change this one column

Comment: The problem is that it still resizes the entire table.